# Is the log norm square of a holomorphic function plurisubharmonic?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables, hermitian-matrices

For a reminder a differentiable function $f:\mathbb{C}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is plurisubharmonic iff the matrix
$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z_i\partial\bar{z}_j}$$
is positive semi-definite (wikipedia).

Now let $f:\mathbb{C}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function. Is the  function $\log ||f||^2$ plurisubharmonic ?

Comment: use the equivalent definition, where $h: \mathbb C^n \to \mathbb R \cup -\infty$ is plurisubharmonic iff $h\circ g$ is subharmonic for any holomorphic $g: \mathbb D \to \mathbb C^n$

Comment: Or just restrict to complex lines (a function is plurisubharmonic if it is subharmonic on all complex lines), so really if you can show that a norm square is subharmonic if n=1, then you should be done.